# How to set many properties to neo4j node with python bolt driver?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-bolt

How to do somethink like that:

```
data = {'field1': 'data1', 'field2': '#data2', 'field3': 'data3', 'field4': 'data4'}
r = session.run("MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 287 SET n = {props}", parameters=data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also use a parameter for id

Otherwise using a dictionary for parameters works, not sure about kwargs

```
data = {'field1': 'data1', 'field2': '#data2', 'field3': 'data3', 'field4': 'data4'}
r = session.run("MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {id} SET n += {props}", 
                {'id':287, 'props':data})
```

Comment: Good answer, thnx!